# D3.js : Reading TSV file from Localhost BUT it is returning NULL

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to read a TSV file using the d3.tsv from my localhost HTTP Server. The following is the code snippet:

```
var iris = {}
d3.tsv("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8000/iris.tsv", function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      console.log(data[i].sepalLength);
      iris[i].sepalLength = data[i].sepalLength;
      iris[i].sepalWidth = data[i].sepalWidth;
      iris[i].petalLength = data[i].petalLength;
      iris[i].petalWidth = data[i].petalWidth;
      iris[i].sepcies = data[i].species;
      
  }
});
```

The code returns the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: data is null

Can someone please help me as to why this might be happening? Thank you.

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using?

Comment: @AndrewReid Classic ;-) Keep in mind, though, that even in v5+ `data` should not be null if loading was successful as the second argument would be interpreted as the row conversion function. The URL looks suspicious to me, never seen it that way.

Comment: @AndrewReid The callback itself clearly is a full data handler belonging to d3-request loading prior to v5, I agree. The follow-up issue will be the notorious asynchronous data loading as `iris` is an object from the outer scope.